# d3.json(): fetching 40 (URL?name=variable) is faster than fetching 40 (URL)

Tags: d3.js

I'm miserable and I hope someone can help!

I had a piece of code that was very slow. I have 40 `variables`, for each of them I do the following:

```
for (i=variables.length; i--;) {
  metric = URL?name=variable;
  d3.select( ... get_data(metric)).... // calls to visualize the data 
}

function get_data(metric) { 
  d3.json(metric, function(data) {
     // do stuff 
  }); 
}
```

To make it faster I did the following:

```
for (i=variables.length; i--;) {
  metric = URL;
  d3.select( ... get_data(metric,variable)).... // calls to visualize the data
} 

function get_data(metric,variable) { 
  d3.json(metric, function(data) {
    parse(data, variable) // extract variable related data
    // do stuff 
  }); 
}
```

The new code is at least 6 times faster! but why? Aren't I fetching more data?

EDIT: I went back and and did a `console.log(data)` in the new `get_data` function and surprisingly it did request the whole data (URL) 40 times!! and yet this is faster than doing 40 different (URL?name=variable)

Comment: Because you are making fewer HTTP requests. Establishing a connection takes time. The more connections you make, the more time you "waste" for establishing connections.

Comment: but aren't I making the same number of requests?

Comment: Oh I see now. It's not that you are making just one call, but you are not adding the variable to the URL anymore. So you load forty times the complete data? In that case I believe the browser caches the response after the first request, so the remaining 39 requests are served from the cache (because the URL doesn't change). So after are all, you are making fewer requests.

Comment: okay that's what I was looking for, so it does cache results! now my question is should I make a local variable to hold the data or not?

Comment: Also put your answer in an "answer" to accept

Comment: The best solution would be to just get the data once and then extract the variables you need. There is no need to request the data again if you already have it anyway.

Comment: I kind of don't have control over that because I'm using a library "cubism.js" and you need to give a callback function to it. inside my callback I have the d3.json call. what I can do is hold the data and have an if else statement inside the callback to test whether I should pull new data or not based on time for example

Comment: off course having the if-else statement now does nothing really! it's as fast as not having the if-else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not adding the variable to the URL anymore, so the URL remains constant. I believe the browser caches the response after the first request, so the remaining 39 requests are served from the cache.

So after are all, you are making fewer HTTP requests, which means less time spent on establishing connections.

The "best" solution would be to make only one Ajax request in total:

```
var get_data = (function() {
  var cache = {};

  function doStuff(data, variable) {
    parse(data, variable);
    // do stuff
  }

  return function(metric, variable) {
    if (cache[metric]) {
      doStuff(cache[metric], variable);
    }
    else {
      d3.json(metric, function(data) {
        cache[metric] = data;
        doStuff(data, variable);
      }); 
    }
  };
}());
```

Comment: I disabled the cache in the browser but it is still fast .... restarted everything and still fast

Comment: Mmh, that's strange. Maybe the server side logic to extract the data is just very slow?

Comment: What's a good reference on understanding the browser, the web how everything works behind all that code?

Comment: "browser caches the response after the first request" how does that work? when it sees the d3.json the second time, it refers to the cached response?